# How to take random n elements from array using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, html

I have an array with list of elements.

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.names= [
        {
            value: "q1"
        },
        {
            value: "q2"
        },
        {
            value: "q3"
        }
    ];
});
```

I need to take randomly two elements and assign to a new array. how can i do?

Comment: You need distinct random 2 elements from the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array

Comment: any random 2 elements

Comment: Angular is not a new programming language - what you are looking for is:"how to get random elements from an array in **JavaScript**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use only javascript to get this done. Because AngularJS is not a programming language.

Check this out:

```
if (!Math.getRandomValueBetween) {
    Math.getRandomValueBetween = function (from, to) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    };
}
//USAGE -- Math.getRandomValueBetween(100,1000) //950


if (!Array.prototype.getRandom) {
    Array.prototype.getRandom = function () {
        return this[Math.getRandomValueBetween(0, this.length - 1)];
    };
}
//USAGE -- [1,34,56,76,9,67,5].getRandom();
```

[From KnightCoder gist](https://gist.github.com/KnightCoder/a6163688a35c96da0663)

Comment: how to use this with my requirement

Comment: `names= [
        {
            value: "q1"
        },
        {
            value: "q2"
        },
        {
            value: "q3"
        }
    ];

    var newArray = [];
    newArray.push(names.getRandom());
    newArray.push(names.getRandom());`